# generate a random number between 1 and x where a lower number is more likely than a higher one

Tags: php, math, random

This is more of a maths/general programming question, but I am programming with PHP is that makes a difference.

I think the easiest way to explain is with an example.

If the range is between 1 and 10.

I want to generate a number that is between 1 an 10 but is more likely lower than high.

The only way I can think is generate an array with 10 elements equal to 1, 9 elements equal to 2, 8 elements equal to 3.....1 element equal to 10. Then generate a random number based on the number of elements.

The trouble is I am potentially dealing with 1 - 100000 and that array would be ridiculously big.

So how best to do it?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of being random

Comment: No, it doesn't defeat the purpose. He simply wants to map the uniform density to another distributiony, which is quite common for Monte Carlo applications. @OP: Could you please provide a distribution function?

Comment: As nikic says, you haven't provided enough information. You need to tell us how much more likely a 1 is than a 10. If you can write down the distribution function you want then you are probably halfway to solving your problem.

Comment: You cant call something random if you are forcing a result

Comment: @Woot: What is your understanding of "random"? A random variable has a distribution function. And the distribution only rarely is linear.

Comment: He's not "forcing" any one result, though. He's simply more likely to pull certain results than others. Think of it like this: I have a bag with 15 cards in it. Five cards have "1" written on them, four have "2", three "3", two "4", and one "5". I draw a card at random from the bag. The result is still random, but I'm five times as likely to get a 1 (a low number) as I am to get a 5 (the high number). I haven't forced any result, but I did weight the random result more heavily towards low numbers.

Comment: actually you can still call it random, weighted random numbers are quite common in a lot of applications. think of it this way... let's say you want to flip a coin, but rather than a 1/2 :: 1/2 head tail distribution you want a 1/3 :: 2/3 favouring tails. (let's say it's weighted coin), You still can't tell whether the next flip will be head or tail (random) but the likeliness is defined by that 1/3::2/3  weight.  This problem is probabilistically equivalent of picking a token out of 3 tokens (1 red, 2 blue) from a bag.

Comment: Or just throw a pair of dice. You're six times more likely to get a seven (probability 6/36) than to get a 1 or 12 (probability 1/36), and yet this *is* considered random for several applications. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR — I was about to use that very example.  random =/= even distribution

Comment: Isn't it impossible to get a 1 when you roll two dice?

Comment: @Lotus Notes:  I assumed they meant 2 or 12.

Comment: What distribution? Exponential, Zipf, Bernoulli, other?

Comment: The strict definition of random is that a function that makes random numbers, when called, will produce a number totally unrelated to future or past numbers (so any number is equally likely). The mistake is in assuming that the property of randomness applies to sets of numbers, and not to generators of number sets. Any number set is random, but the properties of a random number generator must have particular properties to be considered "random".

Comment: If you could generate an infinite amount of numbers from this "random" generator, then the distribution would be equal, but any subset of that would not be (it would have some form of inequalities in the distribution)

Comment: For an example: a perfect random number generator could generate "4,4,4,4,4,4,4", and "5,2,6,2,8,1,9" equally probably.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0 and a random number!

Comment: But it is inefficient. It requires generating two random numbers ;)

Comment: @nikic: You generate a random number in 1 to n twice, which means 2log(n) bits of randomness. For the distribution in the question, this is optimal, as 2log(n) = log(n^2).

Comment: This does give a declining probability but it is not the same as is generated by the algorithm presented in the question. Instead it gives a probability of sum(1/i:n)/n where n is the max and i is the integer in question.

Comment: Output graphics (density) in http://a.imageshack.us/img710/8336/rndrnd.png ... for the faithless :D

Answer (score 10):

Generate a number between 1 and foo(n), where foo runs an algorithm over n (e.g. a logarithmic function). Then reverse foo() on the result.

Answer (score 4):

Generate number `n` which is `0 <= n < 1`, multiply it by itself, than multiply by `x`, run floor on it and add 1. Sorry I used php toooo long ago to write code in it

Comment: @Zano, because he is squaring a number less than 1, the number group at the lower end of the range

Comment: @murgatroid99: Of course, I didn't pay attention on the < 1. *Note to self:* don't play with the baby while commenting SO answers

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
$rand = floor(100000 * (rand(0, 1)*rand(0, 1)));
```

Or something along these lines

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two (or more?) ways to map uniform density to any distribution function: [Inverse transformation sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) and [Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). I think in your case you should use the former.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and simple:

```
rand(1, rand(1, n))
```

Comment: Its a nice simple solution... but I found that it sometimes results in 0. It should be rand(1,rand(1,n). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is generate a random number over a greater interval (preferably floating point), and map that into [1,10] in a nonuniform way. Exactly what way depends on **how** much more likely you want a 1 to be than a 9 or 10.

For C language solutions, see [these libraries](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/unuran/). You may find use for [this in PHP](http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/122799.php3).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it looks like you want to draw a random number from a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) rather than the [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). On the wiki page cited above there is a section which specifically states how you can use the continuous distribution to generate a pseudo-Poisson distribution... [check it out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables). Note that you may want to test different values of λ to ensure the distribution works as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what distribution you want to have exactly, i.e., what number should appear with what probability.

For instance, for even n you could do the following: generate one integer random number x between 1 and n/2 and generate a second number between 1 and n+1. If y > x you generate x otherwise you generate n-x+1. This should give you the distribution in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give the requested distribution:

Generate a random number in the range 1 .. x. Generate another one in the range 1 .. x+1.
Return the minimum of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about how your array idea changes the probabilities. Normally every element from 1 to n has a probability of 1/n and is thus equally likely.

Since you have n entries for 1, n-1 entries for 2...1 entry for n, then the total number of entries you have is an arithmetic series. The sum of an arithmetic series counting from 1 to n is n(1+n)/2.  So now we know every element's probability should use that as the denominator.

Element 1 has n entries, so it's probability is n/n(1+n)/2. Element 2 is n-1/n(1+n)/2 ... n is 1/n(1+n)/2.  That gives a general formula of the numerator as n+1 -i, where i is the number you are checking.  That means we now have a function for the probability of any element as n-i+1/n(1+n)/2. all probabilities are between 0 and 1 and sum to 1 by definition, and that is key to the next step.

How can we use this function to skew the number of times an element appears? It's easier with continuous distributions (ie doubles instead of ints) but we can do it. First let's make an array of our probabilities, call it c, and make a running sum of them (cumsum) and store it back in c.  If that doesn't make sense, its just a loop like

```
for(j=0; j < n-1; j++)
   if(j) c[j]+=c[j-1]
```

Now that we have this cumulative distribution, generate a number i from 0 to 1 (a double, not an int. We can check if i is between 0 and c[0], return 1. if i is between c[1] and c[2] return 2...all the way up to n.   e.g.

`for(j=0; j < n=1;j++)
   if(i %lt;= c[j]) return i+1`

This will distribute the integers according to the probabilities you have calculated.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
//get random number between 1 and 10,000
$random = mt_rand(1, 10000); 
?>
```

Comment: While this returns a random number, it doesn't actually answer OP's question.